# How can I set a request code under different conditions for my activity to bypass onActivityResult?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, activity-transition

I have a program that allows me to store data(pictures and metadata with the taken picture) during the execution of a picture being taking with the android system camera activity... but I have code in place to make sure that the user enters data into a popup activity before the camera activity is displayed by using the `OnActivityResult` function(this way the user's photo has information that is stored as metadata in my firebase database). I was wondering If I can set a request code that wouldn't be equal to the `REQUESTCODE2` so that under the condition that my back button is pressed(which will still result in the `REQUESTCODE2` being returned for the `com.example.myapplication.nameofphoto` activity, which then will trigger `takepic()`) I can purposely make sure that the request code is faulty so that `takepic()` does not trigger and I don't store null data into my database.

for your information: `nameofpersonvar` , and `nameofphotovar` are both in a different class and is the information from the popup activity

```
private const val   REQUESTCODE = 2
private const val   REQUESTCODE2 = 3

fun take_pic(){
    val takephotoIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    if (takephotoIntent.resolveActivity(this.packageManager) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takephotoIntent, REQUESTCODE)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable To access Camera... ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show()
    }


}
        photoButton.setOnClickListener {
            val action3 = Intent(this , com.example.myapplication.nameofphoto::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(action3, REQUESTCODE2 )

    }




override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (REQUESTCODE == requestCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //Compressing the bitmap(image) into a byte[] to match the input of the .putbytes method
            val userimage = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
            val byteoutput = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            userimage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100 , byteoutput)
            val data = byteoutput.toByteArray()
            //ref to the firebase "bucket" database
            val storageinfo = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/Images" )
            //extra data that shows who the images belong to (users)

            val metadatastoreage = storageMetadata {
                setCustomMetadata("Name of person" , nameofpersonvar)
                setCustomMetadata("Name of photo" , nameofphotovar)}
           storageinfo.putBytes(data, metadatastoreage)



        }else if (requestCode ==REQUESTCODE2) {
            take_pic()

        }
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then why don't you send some result code different from the back press method of the current activity opened and check if the result is successful then take pick otherwise do something.

send this as result code from back press method. `RESULT_CANCELED`

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (REQUESTCODE == requestCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        //Compressing the bitmap(image) into a byte[] to match the input of the .putbytes method
        val userimage = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
        val byteoutput = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        userimage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100 , byteoutput)
        val data = byteoutput.toByteArray()
        //ref to the firebase "bucket" database
        val storageinfo = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/Images" )
        //extra data that shows who the images belong to (users)

        val metadatastoreage = storageMetadata {
            setCustomMetadata("Name of person" , nameofpersonvar)
            setCustomMetadata("Name of photo" , nameofphotovar)}
       storageinfo.putBytes(data, metadatastoreage)
       return
    }

   if (requestCode ==REQUESTCODE2 && resultcode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        take_pic()
   } else {
        //back pressed do something.
        //finish etc
    }
}
```

**Edit**: You can override the onBackPressed() in the popup activity and send some data using intent to the parent activity. for ex.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
// TODO Add extras or a data URI to this intent as appropriate.
resultIntent.putExtra("user_pic_click", "some data");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: I really dont understand like what you are getting at , could you break it down a bit more for my understanding?

Comment: Like for example , when the backbutton is pressed is the result code Result Canceled?

Comment: the back button being the one of android os  near the "home button" built in to the device

Comment: what i'm saying when back button is pressed you should receive a result code different then success this way you can differentiate between if the operation was success. or not. if the class is created by you then you can manually send the canceled code.

Comment: using your method doesn't trigger the take_pic() function.

Comment: in what case is the activity considered .result_ok?

Comment: Does the activity have to be closed? or can it just be hidden??

Comment: i'm not sure if the requirements are clear can you elaborate a bit more. or post the code for starting activity. will help to understand the problem.

Comment: simply put , I am trying to see if I can change the request code of the activity under certain circumstances...

Comment: yes but before making a request to open activity,  not after you opened the child activity.

Comment: I am trying to have the user press a button. After the button is pressed I would like them to enter data, and after data is entered , I would like them to press a button to submit that data, then this will trigger the take_pic() function that is in the code above..

Comment: I am trying to have the user press this  button in the popup activity, which will close the activity.. and on the closure of that activity , I would like to trigger the take_pic() function , would you like me to update the problem to elaborate on what else is in place?